# Strange redirect in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC app with login functionality and I have several empty controlls, for example: Home.
Home Controller does not contain anything at all. The View for the Home controller is a default Home View created by Visual Studio.
And there is a strange thing:
When I run my web app, it starts from Account/Login
But if I click on the menu (or even if I type the path to Home/Index) it automatically redirects me back to Account/Login
If I type Account/SignUp - it works fine.
But if I go to any View of my empty controllers I get this strange redirect.
I have not had this problem in the other projects.
So I'm a bit stuck. Please advise.

Comment: Do you have an authorize attribute on the other controllers/actions?

Comment: You possibly have the Authorize attribute applied via Global filters, and because you are not logged in, you automatically get redirected to the login page?

Comment: ops...yes, I do :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as a best practice you *should* have the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) applied to the whole site. It works best to do that in your `FilterConfig` file.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Then you should use the AllowAnonymous attribute to selectively make parts of your site available without logging in (such as the home page).

```
public class HomeController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) for details.